# Doctrine 1.2 not creating tables from models in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-1.2

I'm trying to create tables from models by using:

```
Doctrine::createTablesFromModels(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models');
```

Unlike generating the models from a Yaml file, which worked just fine, this does nothing at all. No errors, no warnings, nothing. The tables are not created. If I run the code below, it works just fine too:

```
Doctrine::dropDatabases();
```

So the database connection does work and the permissions are setup right. I've googled it in ten different ways without getting any helpful answers, so now I'm asking here.

Here is one of my base classes:

```
<?php

/**
 * BaseUser
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $firstName
 * @property string $lastName
 * @property string $profileText
 * @property integer $role_id
 * @property Role $Role
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $UserDetail
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $CalendarItem
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $NewsItem
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $Link
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $TwitterUser
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $Tweet
 * 
 * @package    ##PACKAGE##
 * @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
 * @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 6820 2009-11-30 17:27:49Z jwage $
 */
abstract class BaseUser extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('user');
        $this->hasColumn('email', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '255',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('password', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '255',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('firstName', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '255',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('lastName', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '255',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('profileText', 'string', null, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => '',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('role_id', 'integer', 8, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 8,
             ));

        $this->option('collate', 'utf8_unicode_ci');
        $this->option('charset', 'utf8');
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasOne('Role', array(
             'local' => 'role_id',
             'foreign' => 'id'));

        $this->hasMany('UserDetail', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id'));

        $this->hasMany('CalendarItem', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id'));

        $this->hasMany('NewsItem', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id'));

        $this->hasMany('Link', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id'));

        $this->hasMany('TwitterUser', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id'));

        $this->hasMany('Tweet', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id'));

        $timestampable0 = new Doctrine_Template_Timestampable();
        $softdelete0 = new softDelete();
        $this->actAs($timestampable0);
        $this->actAs($softdelete0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could we see one of your models + base class?

Comment: I added one of the base classes. I haven't changed the models, so they're just empty classes extending the base classes.

Comment: I could of course just make the tables by hand, but that's just a work around and I really just want the normal code to work like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I was using the softdelete functionality and I forgot to set:

```
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_USE_DQL_CALLBACKS, true);
```

This is necessary for softdelete to work. I also found out that in my generated models it used the wrong code for softdeletion:

```
$softdelete0 = new softDelete();
```

Instead of:

```
$softdelete0 = new Doctrine_Template_SoftDelete();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had face this issue before that and after 3 days of searching i couldn't find a solution 
at the end of it i had moved to use symfony cli tool to generate sql and create db from yaml file

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, rather a way around a supposedly straight forward problem. Granted, you can't yet give a full answer to the question as the OP is yet to post useful information, but I wouldn't be so quick to offer a completely different method to handling table generation.

Comment: its just workaround  to save the time , and get the job done ,if you can afford an answer i will be happy to use it

Comment: Again, its rather difficult without first seeing your models & base classes

Comment: i understand , and i am willing to see you fix it

Comment: I'm not using Symfony, so I can't use the cli tool.